# Can you use a public instance variable of one class within another class(A) in c++?

Tags: c++

A simple hypothetical example:

#### `A.h`

```
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int m_variable = 5;
}
```

#### `B.cpp`

```
include iostream>

using namespace std;

void B::method() {
    // Why do get an error stating 'invalid use of non-static data member on this line?
    int x = (A::m_variable) * 2;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: Provide a definition for B and someone will be able to answer, this is incomplete as is.

Comment: You can't do it like this: you are not referring to a specific instance of A, so how could you access the variable of an instance then? You need an actual object of type A, and then access it. Either that, or just access static data member. Also note: this Q is not gamedev specific.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, no. But it is possible if you write it differently. There are a couple possible ways to do this. If you have a definition of the class `B` like this:

```
class B : public A {
    // ... whatever
};
```

In this case, `B` [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)n `A`, so `B` inherits all of `A`'s member variables. Since `A` declared `m_variable` as public, `B` can set it however it wishes.

Another possibility is if `B` is declared like this:

```
class B {
    // ... whatever
    private:
        A someVar;
};
```

In this case, `B` [has a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)n `A`. So `B` can access all of `A`'s public member variables. You would have to write the line in question like this:

```
int x = someVar.m_variable * 2;
```

A third option is if `A` declares `m_variable` as `static` and `public`. In this case all instances of `A` share the same copy of the `static` variable. You would have to declare `A` like this:

```
class A {
public:
    static int m_variable;
};
```

In this case, `B`'s code would work exactly as you have written it. You would access the variable via `A::m_variable`.

In your example, you're reading the variable, which is fine. Note that directly changing a `public` variable in another class would be a maintenance headache.